# HyperV 2008 with HyperV 2012

Tags: hyper-v-server-2008-r2, hyper-v-server-2012

We currently have a Windows 2008R2 Hyper V server with 4 VMs. We would like to get another Windows hyper v server host to add a few new servers for a long term project.

My question is if we go with 2012 hyper v host are the 2008 hyper v VMs guest capable of running on hyper v 2012? We would like to have another Host that can be used as a backup.

Answer (score 1):

And why do you not just update the 2008 R2 Hyper-V server to 2012 R2, too? It is not like the Hyper-V Server has big licensing costs.

Answer (score 1):

We've successfully (and IMHO quite easily) have imported VM's created in HyperV 2008 R2 to a newer HyperV 2012 R2 host in many occasions. This was by design.

The only problem I can think of is if you are trying to do this procedure the other way around, from 2012 R2 --> 2008 R2 if you are not careful to check the [generation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn282285.aspx) of the virtual machines you are trying to migrate.

Basically, HyperV 12 R2 now has the option to create Gen 2 VM's which have new functionality -but are not required to run on a 2012 R2 server (see link) BUT will not run on HyperV 08 R2. So, basically, unless you specifically need one of the new functionalities afforded by the Gen 2 VMs, and you will still have the HyperV 2008 R2 running in your environment, you can always choose to stick with Gen 1 Vms -which are still totally supported by 2012 R2.